# How to populate multiple prompts in a row in Cypress before initial page load

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing, stub, stubbing

Cypress newbie here.
I'm trying to populate data into 3 different prompts that appear before the page loads completely. These values are then added into session storage. It is my understanding that since  the site is not fully loaded I can't chain off `cy.visit()` so I've been using the `onBeforeLoad` so I can populate the data for these prompts:

```
before(function() {
        cy.visit(base_url, {
            onBeforeLoad(win) {
                cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns('someString').as('stub1')
                cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns('someOtherString').as('stub2')
                cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns('anotherString').as('stub3')
            }
        })
    })
```

The issue is that when I look under "Spies/Stubs" I only see the `stub1` being used 3 times as opposed to 3 different stubs being used once.

I also get the error
`TypeError: Attempted to wrap prompt which is already wrapped`

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

**EDIT:**

Doing something like

```
before(function() {
        cy.visit(base_url, {
            onBeforeLoad(win) {
                demo_site_info.forEach(element => {
                    cy.stub(win, 'prompt').callsFake(() => {
                        return element
                    })
                    
                });
            }
        })
    })
```

yields a TypeError:
`Attempted to wrap prompt which is already wrapped`

Answer (score 1):

Using `callsFake(fn)` allows multiple fake values.

```js
it('fakes return values multiple times', () => {

  const mod = {
    doit: () => 'done'
  }

  let call = 0
  const fakes = ['done1', 'done2', 'done3']
  cy.stub(mod, 'doit').callsFake(() => {
    return fakes[call++]
  })

  console.log(mod.doit())  // done1
  console.log(mod.doit())  // done2
  console.log(mod.doit())  // done3
  console.log(mod.doit())  // undefiend
})
```

Comment: before(function() {
        cy.visit(base_url, {
            onBeforeLoad(win) {
                demo_site_info.forEach(element => {
                    cy.stub(win, 'prompt').callsFake(() => {
                        return element
                    })
                });
            }
        })
    })
Yields an "Attempted to wrap prompt which is already wrapped" error

Comment: Please look at my example, I stub ***only once*** and `callsFake()` handles the multiple calls with a different response. Why did you use `forEach`?